# WPF VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(MyMap) returns 1 (Border) when MyMap.Children.Count = 1237

Tags: c#, wpf, bing-maps

At my WPF BingMaps app I add 1237 "System.Windows.Controls.Image" images with command "MyMap.Children.Add(image);"

When I want to remove them I try to use the method below.Here I get mychildren result = 1237 but VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(MyMap) returns 1 (Border type). What is wrong here? Thks

```
private void limpaaerop()
    {
        int mychildren = MyMap.Children.Count; // result = 1237
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(MyMap); i++)
        {
            Visual childVisual = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(MyMap, i);
            if (childVisual is System.Windows.Controls.Image)
            {
                MyMap.Children.Remove((UIElement)childVisual);
            }
        }
    }
```

Inside the Maingrid Xaml

```
  </UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="maingrid" Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      .....
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        ....
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel x:Name="mapStack" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="12" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="9">
        <map:Map x:Name="MyMap"  Margin="0,0,0,0"  />
    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should iterate through `MyMap.Children` instead of `VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(MyMap)`:

```
private void limpaaerop()
{
    int mychildren = MyMap.Children.Count;
    for (int i = mychildren - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        UIElement childVisual = MyMap.Children[i];
        if (childVisual is System.Windows.Controls.Image)
        {
            MyMap.Children.Remove(childVisual);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thks a lot @mm8. It works pefectly which is the most important. I will leave the understanding of "VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount" for another time.

Comment: I checked your answer so I hope this means acceptation